# iterator for vector of structures in thrust

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to get access to vector elements in this manner

```
struct point
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
};

...
thrust::device_vector<point> devPoints(hPoints.begin(), hPoints.end());

for(thrust::device_vector<point>::iterator iter = devPoints.begin(); iter != devPoints.end(); iter++) 
{
    std::cout << iter->x << " " << iter->y << " " << std::endl; (1)
}
```

device_vector was initialized properly. I get following errors:

```
error: expression must have pointer type (at 1)
error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "const thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<point>>" to "thrust::device_ptr<point>" exists
          detected during instantiation of "Pointer thrust::experimental::iterator_facade<Derived, Pointer, Value, Space, Traversal, Reference, Difference>::operator->() const [with Derived=thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<point>>, Pointer=thrust::device_ptr<point>, Value=point, Space=thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag, Traversal=thrust::random_access_traversal_tag, Reference=thrust::device_reference<point>, Difference=ptrdiff_t]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this one was a bit more complicated than I expected :)
Here are the results of my investigations:

Your problem comes from thrust's implementation. Thrust uses a type called `device_reference` which, as its documentation says: http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/classthrust_1_1device__reference.html

> `device_reference` acts as a
>   reference-like object to an object
>   stored in device memory.
>   `device_reference` is not intended to be
>   used directly; rather, this type is
>   the result of deferencing a
>   `device_ptr`. Similarly, taking the
>   address of a `device_reference` yields a
>   `device_ptr`.

However, there are some cases when we are dealing implicitly with `device_reference`. For example, when a device_reference is passed as a parameter to functions waiting for POD (more or less what you are trying to do with `operator<<`), the following problem appears:

> Another common case where a
>   `device_reference` cannot directly be
>   used in place of its referent object
>   occurs when passing them as parameters
>   to functions like `printf` which have
>   varargs parameters. Because varargs
>   parameters must be Plain Old Data, a
>   **`device_reference` to a POD type requires a cast**
>   when passed to printf:

Having said that, all you have to do is to cast your `device_reference` to the POD you're handling. In your case, you'd do:

```
for(thrust::device_vector<point>::iterator iter = devPoints.begin(); iter != devPoints.end(); iter++)  {
   std::cout << (static_cast<point>(*iter)).x << " " << (static_cast<point>(*iter)).y << std::endl;
}
```

In my opinion, this is not the most elegant solution, I'd rather use the `std::copy` algorithm to print the content of your `point` class. Thus, I've written a small example file, using your `point` class and printing it using three different ways:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct point
{
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
};

__host__
point getRandomPoint() {
        point p;

        p.x = rand();
        p.y = rand();

        return p;
}

__host__
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const point& p) {
        os << "[ " << p.x << " ; " << p.y << " ]";
        return os;
}

int main() {
        // fill the host_vector with random points
        thrust::host_vector<point> hPoints(512);
        thrust::generate(hPoints.begin(), hPoints.end(), getRandomPoint);

        // copy hPoints content to device memory
        thrust::device_vector<point> devPoints(hPoints.begin(), hPoints.end());

        // first way 
        for(thrust::device_vector<point>::iterator iter = devPoints.begin(); iter != devPoints.end(); iter++)  {
                std::cout << (static_cast<point>(*iter)).x << " " << (static_cast<point>(*iter)).y << std::endl;
        }

        // second way
        for(thrust::device_vector<point>::iterator iter = devPoints.begin(); iter != devPoints.end(); iter++)
        {
                std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        }

        // third way
        std::copy(devPoints.begin(), devPoints.end(), std::ostream_iterator< point >(std::cout, "  $  ") );

        return 0;
}
```

Now, it's up to you to choose the one you prefer!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help.

Comment: @qutron: I got through your problem! Check my answer again. It should work for you now.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << iter->x << " " << iter->y << " " << std::endl; 
                                      ^^^^
```

:))

Comment: @qutrun: What else is there that we don't know?

Comment: Nothing interesting. hPoints is a host_vector. It was initialized properly and it works fine with this approach. I have found that container types in Thrust are limited to fundamental types. Perhaps my errors are connected with that.