# How to store the vector.begin() iterator of template type in thrust?

Tags: c++, cuda, iterator, gpgpu, thrust

When I attempt to assign a variable to that iterator, i get the error: `expected a ";"`, where `vec` is a `thrust::device_vector<my_type>`, `j` is some `int`, and `my_type` is a template type:

```
for (thrust::device_vector<my_type>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i < vec.end(); i += j) Foo(i);
```

Is this the correct way to loop over the vector? Am I declaring `i` as the correct type?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592765/1410711) might be useful to you....Further,you might wanna try `i!=vec.end()`..

Comment: Probably need to put `typename` in front if this code is inside a template: `typename thrust::device_vector<my_type>::iterator i = ...`

Comment: @JaredHoberock, thanks - that seems to have fixed it. So where exactly do we need to use `typename` in general? It seems random that I was declaring `thrust::device_vector<my_type>` without any errors but just hit a wall when it came to `thrust::device_vector<my_type>::iterator`.

Comment: You need to use `typename` when you're talking about a dependent type inside a template. A Stack Overflow search should provide the details.

Comment: BTW, the C++11 way is a lot easier: `for (auto i = vec.begin() ...` (can't use the `for (int i : vec)` form since this loop skips elements when j!=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard containers use iterators for traversing through a collection of other objects (i.e. its elements), since iterator is abstract concept implemented in all standard containers, you can implement iterators in the following way:

```
typename thrust::device_vector<my_type>::iterator it = vec.begin();
for (it; it != vec.end(); it = it+j) 
   Foo(*it);
```

Here's a reference to STL containers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/